# django import error in django-import-export

Tags: django, django-import-export

I am using django-import-export. I am getting errors in importing data to a database with foreignkey value.

```
class Meta:

model = model

fields=('id','title','Model_code','Chipset','chipset_description','image','Brand__title','Cat')`
```

Here Brand is used as foreign-key and I get the title by using Brand__title . It works perfectly for exporting but when importing it through an error for foreignkey is null.

```
Line number: 1 - null value in column "Brand_id" of relation "firmApp_model" violates not-null constraint DETAIL: Failing row contains (6, f16, sd, images/sample_3pahsfV.jfif, gf, kjkj, null). None, f16, sd, images/sample_3pahsfV.jfif, gf, 1, kjkj, 1
```

Comment: as stated in documentation of django-import-export, `Following relationship fields sets field as readonly, meaning this field will be skipped when importing data.` so it will work perfectly when exporting but not on imports

Comment: https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_widgets.html#import_export.widgets.ForeignKeyWidget with this widget you can do imports as you want

Comment: Thanks @FabianVlemenz, your  answer help me to resolve issue